# How can I prohibit my Java application runs on Windows?

Tags: java, windows

I wrote a Java application because the official application is only available for Windows. Because I want to ensure that I don't get into trouble I want to prohibit that it runs on Windows.

What can I check to know if the application runs on Windows and therefore immediately quit the application?

Other advises are welcome, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) library for this. It has a `SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS`, whose purpose is to do this for you. Check this `boolean`, and if it's set, then use `System.exit(1)` (or some appropriate value).

It'll save you worrying about whether you're correctly interpreting the result of the `System.getProperty()` call.

By the way, you might consider getting your application to launch the official application instead of exiting. You could do it either way.

Comment: I have already commons-lang in my project. Otherwise I would do it like  @prashant thakre answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

If its windows use

> System.exit(-1)

Comment: I would do it your way, but I already have commons lang in my project.